# Creating a tapering layout

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I create a tapering header in an Android app as in the image here

[image]

I am not sure on how to achieve a tapering effect on any layout. Is it possible to get this effect? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this down voted? Please provide comments for any down voting.

Comment: 1)overlap layout on layout and use show hide on click 2) use image

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InclinedVIew extends View
{
   private Context mContext;
   Paint paint ;
   Path path;
   private int w, h;
   public InclinedVIew(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(ctx, attrs);
        mContext = ctx;
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        path = new Path();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        w = getMeasuredWidth(); h = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        path.reset();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo(0,h-100); //add path here replace 100 by your height
        path.lineTo(w, h); 
        path.lineTo(w,0);
        path.lineTo(0,0);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

This class will create the tapered view. Tweak the `path` variables to get the inclination on the side you want.

Comment: This looks cool. However can you let me know how to increase the height on the tapering end as in the image in my question. [Here](https://ibm.box.com/s/bmobyrs1khns7entyxtoby033ey0olo1) is the output from the above code.